# How can I get the nested collection from firestore database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have already managed to get root collection and it's document contents in a recycler view.

But now im having struggle to do the same but with the nested collection.

Say i have this type of root collection:

[image]

with these two sub-collections:

[image]

so it goes like this:

*products -> "date" -> "brandName" -> "productName" -> productDetails*

with such structure (*if it's correct*) i want to display a simple list in recycler view with only these items: **timeStamp**, **status** and **ltd**

And after that, for example, when i click on **26-12-2022** item in recyclerView i want to display a list of the brands which are inside **26-12-2022** collection in another fragment.

with a root collection structure i do that with these following code:

**DashboardFragment.kt** *(where i get data in recyclerView)*

```
fun readFromDb(){
        val db = db.collection("products")
        db.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
            if (e != null) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e)
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }

            if (snapshot != null) {
                val product = snapshot.toObjects<Items>() //Items here is my data class
                testAdapter.submitList(product)

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Current data: null")
            }
        }
    }
```

**Items.kt**

```
data class Items(
        val ltd:String = "",
        val brandAbbreviation:String = "",
        val brand:String = "",
        val productName:String = "",
        val clientName:String = "",
        val coworker:String = "",
        val status:String = "",
        val boxNumber:Int = 0,
        val timestamp: String = "",
    )
```

bonus question: is the firestore structure correct for such a case?

Thanks!

Comment: i've found the answer for the main question but bonus question remains unanswered :)

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add nested collection to "db" variable like this:

```
val db = db.collection("products").document("26-12-2022").collection("Pianca")
```